# opengl - does glBindTexture overwrite contents of the active texture unit

Tags: c++, opengl

I was finding the relationship between `glActiveTexture(...)` and `glBindTexture(...)` and I found an [awesome answer here](https://community.khronos.org/t/when-to-use-glactivetexture/64913), the very top answer(the author/user Alfonse) gives us a pseudocode for how the both functions behave, and I understood most of it. But, in it he mentions in calls such as this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 5);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, object);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);
```

> but one often binds a texture to the context just to upload some data or to modify it. It doesn’t matter at that point which texture unit you bind it to, so there’s no need to set the current texture unit. glTexImage2D doesn’t care if the current active texture is 0, 1, 40, or whatever.

So my problem is: 
when generating two texture we do something like this:

```
 glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

 glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);    


//some more code
//inside the render loop
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

glDrawElements(...); glSwapBuffers();
//end of render loop
```

**Notice**, in the code before the render loop, I have used two texture `glBindTexture(...)` without calling `glActiveTexture(...)`. Since, the default active texture unit is: `GL_TEXTURE0`, does this mean the parameters set for `texture1` is *overwritten* by `texture2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, texture parameters (set by `glTexParameter`) are set for a specific texture (the one that's currently bound to the active texture unit), not for a texture unit (not for one of `GL_TEXTUREi`, that is).

---

Note that your use of `glTextureParameteri` incorrect. Rather than `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, it expects a handle of a texture, as returned by `glGenTextures`<sup>1</sup>. You're confusing it with `glTexParameteri`, which indeed can be called with `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

<sup>1</sup> As noted by @derhass, `glGenTextures` (unlike `glCreateTextures`) merely reserves the handle. A texture with this handle is created only when you pass it to `glBindTexture`. It doesn't matter if you use `glTexParameter`, but if you want to use `glTextureParameteri` and other functions that operate directly on texture handles, it might be important.

Comment: "rather than `GL_TEXTURE_2D`, it expects a handle of a texture, as returned by `glGenTextures`". That's one of the more subtle oddities with GL's direct state access, as th `glGen*()` functions actually only reserve names without creating anything, khronos had to add `glCreate*()`. So to be precise, the statement would be "it expects a handle of a texture, as returned by `glCreateTextures` or one which was reserved by `glGenTextures` followed by `glBindTexture` to actually create it".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat , how do we figure out what functions work on texture units and what functions work for the currently bound texture? It seems(like `glBindTexture()`) functions can work on both

Comment: @derhass,  how do we figure out what functions work on texture units and what functions work for the currently bound texture? It seems(like glBindTexture()) functions can work on both

Comment: @juztcodeby reading the documentation. Note that `glBindTexture` never affects the currently bound texture object, it just establishes that binding.

Comment: @derhass , I did read the doc: http://docs.gl/gl4/glBindTexture some things are technically languaged so hard to understand, but, this mentions nothing about the relationship betn texture units and glbindTexture() and glActiveTexture. If you can, could you please point it out?

Comment: @juztcode: [OpenGL 4.6 core profile specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf), chapter 8 "Textures and Samplers".

Comment: @derhass, are all texture parameters set by gl....() parameters set for a specific texture(currently bound to the active texture unit)?

Comment: @juztcode *"relationship betn texture units and glbindTexture() and glActiveTexture"* In short: for most types of GL objects, only one object can be bound (or "active") at a time. E.g. if you bind a vertex buffer using `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, x);`, then the previously bound vertex buffer will be unbound automatically. But for textures, there's more than one "binding point" (they're called "texture units", and named `GL_TEXTUREi` (i >= 0)). You can have more than one 2D texture (`GL_TEXTURE_2D`) bound at the same time, as long as they're bound to different units. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] `glActiveTexture` selects the active texture unit (`GL_TEXTURE0` by default). Subsequent `glBindTexture` calls bind stuff to that unit. (Only one `GL_TEXTURE_2D` can be bound to a unit at the same time.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, are all texture parameters set by gl....() parameters set for a specific texture(currently bound to the active texture unit)?

Comment: @derhass It's hard to speak for all the functions, but yes, I think most of them work on the texture itself rather than a texture unit. By the way, you don't need to post separate comments for me. You can just ping `@derhass`, and I'll be notified because the comments are under my answer.

Comment: @juztcode: https://github.com/derhass/miscstuff/raw/master/OpenGL/texture_units.pdf